# Mergesort Getting an Error in F#

Tags: f#, mergesort, f#-scripting

```
let rec merge = function
| ([], ys) -> ys
| (xs, []) -> xs
| (x::xs, y::ys) -> if x < y then x :: merge (xs, y::ys)
                    else y :: merge (x::xs, ys)

let rec split = function
| [] -> ([], [])
| [a] -> ([a], [])
| a::b::cs -> let (M,N) = split cs
              (a::M, b::N)

let rec mergesort = function
| [] -> []
| L -> let (M, N) = split L
       merge (mergesort M, mergesort N)


mergesort [5;3;2;1]  // Will throw an error.
```

I took this code from here [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303740/f-spacing-and-mergesort) but when I run the mergesort with a list I get an error:

```
stdin(192,1): error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has been inferred to have generic type
    val it : '_a list when '_a : comparison
```

How would I fix this problem? What is the problem? The more information, the better (so I can learn :) )

Comment: watch to below link it will help you to solve problem
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12643/f-mergesort-code-where-to-improve

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does value restriction happen with MergeSort function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671112/why-does-value-restriction-happen-with-mergesort-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mergesort function is missing a case causing the signature to be inferred by the compiler to be `'a list -> 'b list` instead of `'a list -> 'a list` which it should be. The reason it should be `'a list -> 'a list` is that you're not looking to changing the type of the list in mergesort.

Try changing your mergesort function to this, that should fix the problem:

```
let rec mergesort = function
 | [] -> []
 | [a] -> [a]
 | L -> let (M, N) = split L
        merge (mergesort M, mergesort N)
```

Another problem with your code however is that neither merge nor split is tail recursive and you will therefore get stack overflow exceptions on large lists (try to call the corrected mergesort like this `mergesort [for i in 1000000..-1..1 -> i]`).

You can make your split and merge functions tail recursive by using the accumulator pattern

```
let split list =
  let rec aux l acc1 acc2 =
    match l with
        | [] -> (acc1,acc2)
        | [x] -> (x::acc1,acc2)
        | x::y::tail ->
            aux tail (x::acc1) (y::acc2)
  aux list [] []

let merge l1 l2 = 
  let rec aux l1 l2 result =
    match l1, l2 with
    | [], [] -> result
    | [], h :: t | h :: t, [] -> aux [] t (h :: result)
    | h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2 ->
        if h1 < h2 then aux t1 l2 (h1 :: result)
        else            aux l1 t2 (h2 :: result)
  List.rev (aux l1 l2 [])
```

You can read more about the accumulator pattern [here](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~wallingf/patterns/recursion.html#4); the examples are in lisp but it's a general pattern that works in any language that provides tail call optimization.